# Do you update the x vector on the fly when using Jacobi Method to solve a matrix system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, matrix-equations

I am trying to work out an algorithm (on my own, without looking at Wikipedia, but thanks!) to solve $\textbf{Ax=b}$ using Jacobi Method. I decided to work through a small, generic 3x3 matrix to help me see how to form my code:

$$x^{k=1}_{1} = \frac{1}{a_{11}}(b_{1}-[a_{12}x^{k=0}_{2}+a_{13}x^{k=0}_{3}])$$

My question comes when I want to next solve for $x^{k=1}_{2}$. Do I use the new value of $x_{1}$ where $k=1$ (represented below) or do I use the original value from my first "guess" x vector (k=0)?

$$x^{k=1}_{2} = \frac{1}{a_{22}}(b_{2}-[a_{21}x^{k=1}_{1}+a_{23}x^{k=0}_{3}])$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Jacobi method you use value of all of the elements of $x$ from the previous iteration.  In the Gauss-Seidel method you make use of the values that you've already updated in the current iteration.  You're describing the Gauss-Seidel method in your question.

Comment: I am looking at my text from class right now, and what I have in the first line of latex is definitely Jacobi. Is the second line Gauss-Seidel because I made use of the updated x1? Thanks for your quick response, by the way. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, line 2 of your question is Gauss-Seidel.